# How I format a json of dict

Tags: python, json

```
msg = '{"event":"addChannel","channel":"ok_sub_spot{currency}_{market}_trades"}'
print msg.format(**{'currency': 'usd', 'market': 'btc'})
```

I want to format this but I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo/tests/t_ws.py", line 21, in <module>
    print msg.format(**{'currency': 'usd', 'market': 'btc'})
KeyError: '"event"'
```

I even don't know why I get this error.

Comment: a **cheap** method would be to use `replace`, i.e. `msg.replace('{currency}', 'usd').replace('{market}', 'btc')`, it will work but not the right way to do it.

Comment: where `msg` comes from?

Answer (score 3):

In a format string `{` and `}` are reserved characters indicating a group you wish to replace.  If you actually **want** either of those characters in the string, you need to double them, as `{{` and `}}`, like so:

```
>>> msg = '{{"event":"addChannel","channel":"ok_sub_spot{currency}_{market}_trades"}}'
>>> print msg.format(**{'currency': 'usd', 'market': 'btc'})
{"event":"addChannel","channel":"ok_sub_spotusd_btc_trades"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
msg = "{"+'{"event":"addChannel","channel":"ok_sub_spot{currency}_{market}_trades"}'+"}"
```

Otherwise it will be interpreted `"event"` as a key.